# What's the difference between time(NULL) and time(&timer)

Tags: c

Consider:

```
#include <time.h>

time_t now = time(NULL);
```

vs

```
time_t timer;
time(&timer);
```

Do they both generate the UTC value, and if not, how are they different?

Comment: How about checking the online documentation for `time()` and for that something else, unless it's also `time()`?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] soon.  I recommend making the body of your question self-contained, with the title as a convenient synopsis of the question.  Don't leave crucial information for the question in the title alone.  And be careful about taking short cuts with the notations you use; in general, don't.

Comment: The `time()` function doesn't necessarily return a "UTC value". It returns some representation of the current time.

Comment: Thank you for improving the question. It's much clearer now -- and can easily be answered by reading the documentation for the `time()` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not a lot of difference.  You could, in theory, write:

```
time_t t1;
time_t t2 = time(&t1);
```

This sets both `t1` and `t2` to the same value.

I normally use:

```
time_t t3 = time(0);  // Or NULL
```

because I seldom need two copies of the same time.  It isn't really clear why the dual behaviour was considered desirable, but it was that way in 7th Edition UNIX™ back in 1978, and the interface hasn't been changed.

Note that Standard C (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.27.2.4 'The `time` function') simply says:

> The `time` function determines the current calendar time. The encoding of the value is
>   unspecified.

The POSIX definition of [`time()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/time.html) gives you a more useful definition:

> The `time()` function shall return the value of time in seconds since the Epoch.
>
> The `tloc` argument points to an area where the return value is also stored. If `tloc` is a null pointer, no value is stored.

This is presumably what you mean by 'UTC time'.

Comment: Speculation: `time_t` may have been too big to be returned from a function for early C compilers. It may predate the invention of `long`, and might once have been defined as a struct or as an array of two (16-bit) `int`s.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer, i will stick to using time(0) instead!

Comment: @KeithThompson: it was almost certainly something to do with 32-bit values and 16-bit PDP-11s and so on.  In the 7th Edition, the type was 'long' rather than 'time_t'.